# parse xml using touch xml

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, touchxml

i am new to xml and want to parse it by using touch xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DataSetMenu xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSetMenu.xsd">
  <MenuCategories>
    <MenuCatID>10108</MenuCatID>
    <MenuCatName>SPEICALS</MenuCatName>
    <BusinessEntityID>20137</BusinessEntityID>
    <DisplayIndex>0</DisplayIndex>
    <MenuCatDesc />
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ImagePath />
  </MenuCategories>
  <MenuCategories>
    <MenuCatID>10109</MenuCatID>
    <MenuCatName>GENERAL MENU</MenuCatName>
    <BusinessEntityID>20137</BusinessEntityID>
    <DisplayIndex>1</DisplayIndex>
    <MenuCatDesc />
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ImagePath />
  </MenuCategories>
  <MenuGroups>

    <MenuGroupID>110079</MenuGroupID>
    <MenuCatID>10108</MenuCatID>
    <MenuGroupName>PIZZA&amp;WINGS&amp;DRINK DEAL</MenuGroupName>
    <MenuGroupDesc />
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <DisplayIndex>0</DisplayIndex>
    <MenuTypeID>1</MenuTypeID>
    <ImagePath />
    <ServiceTimeEnforced>false</ServiceTimeEnforced>
    <ServiceStartTime>2013-04-15T11:00:00-05:00</ServiceStartTime>
    <ServiceEndTime>2013-04-15T15:00:00-05:00</ServiceEndTime>
    <Monday>true</Monday>
    <Tuesday>true</Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
    <Thursday>true</Thursday>
    <Friday>true</Friday>
    <Saturday>true</Saturday>
    <Sunday>true</Sunday>
  </MenuGroups>
  <MenuGroups>
    <MenuGroupID>110081</MenuGroupID>
    <MenuCatID>10109</MenuCatID>
    <MenuGroupName>BUILD YOUR OWN PIZZA</MenuGroupName>
    <MenuGroupDesc />
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <DisplayIndex>0</DisplayIndex>
    <MenuTypeID>1</MenuTypeID>
    <ImagePath />
    <ServiceTimeEnforced>false</ServiceTimeEnforced>
    <ServiceStartTime>1900-01-01T11:00:00-06:00</ServiceStartTime>
    <ServiceEndTime>1900-01-01T15:00:00-06:00</ServiceEndTime>
    <Monday>true</Monday>
    <Tuesday>true</Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
    <Thursday>true</Thursday>
    <Friday>true</Friday>
    <Saturday>true</Saturday>
    <Sunday>true</Sunday>
  </MenuGroups>
```

i am trying to use this code

```
//  we will put parsed data in an a array
    NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //  using local resource file
    NSString *XMLPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"20137_ZZ Pizza & Kabob_2013_04_19 01_20_22_Local.xml"];
    NSData *XMLData   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:XMLPath];
    CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:XMLData options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

    NSArray *nodes = NULL;
    //  searching for piglet nodes
    nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//MenuCatID" error:nil];

    for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {
        NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        int counter;
        for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
            //  common procedure: dictionary with keys/values from XML node
            [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];
        }

        //  and here it is - attributeForName! Simple as that.
        [item setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"id"] stringValue] forKey:@"id"];  // <------ this magical arrow is pointing to the area of interest

        [res addObject:item];
        [item release];
    }

    //  and we print our results
    NSLog(@"%@", res);
    [res release];
```

Comment: Where is the question/problem you have faced in it?

Comment: problem is that it dosen t come in for loop

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, KissXML is better for you https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML

Here is example how to parse your XML file

```
// your file name
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"xml"];

// load file content into string
NSString *xmlContent =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// create XMLDocument object
DDXMLDocument *xml = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlContent options:0 error:nil];

// Get root element - DataSetMenu for your XMLfile
DDXMLElement *root = [xml rootElement];

// go through all elements in root element (DataSetMenu element)
for (DDXMLElement *DataSetMenuElement in [root children]) { 
    // if the element name's is MenuCategories then do something
    if ([[DataSetMenuElement name] isEqualToString:@"MenuCategories"]) {
        // get MenuCatID
        NSInteger MenuCatID = [[[DataSetmenuElement elementForName:@"MenuCatID"] objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
    }
}
```

Method elementForName will get you NSArray of all elements with specific name (if you want first then objectAtIndex:0) and thereafter you have to specific type (integerValue, stringValue, doubleValue)

I hope this helps.

Comment: i want to use touchXml if you can help me?

Comment: You are looking for a tutorial -> [Parsin XML with TouchXML](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/parsing-xml-element-attributes-with-touchxml.html)